# About multiple inheritance and ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity

In the following example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "a" << endl; }
    virtual void h() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};
class s1 : public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "s1" << endl; }
};
class s2 : public A {
public:
    virtual void h() { cout << "s2" << endl; }
};
class GS : public s1, public s2 {
public:
};
int main()
{
    s1 *q = new GS;
    q->h();//no problem

    GS a;
    a.h();//error

}
```

Why does `a.h();` give an ambiguity error yet `q->h();` doesn't?

Doesn't `*q` have an instance of `GS` which should cause the same ambiguity problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of multiple inheritance causes two instances of `A` to appear in `GS`. When you use `S1 *q` to access the `GS` instance, it follows the `A` instance associated with `S1`. Since `S1` does not implement `h()`, the output of `q->h()` will be the implementation provided by `A` itself.

If you want `q->h()` to use the implementation provided by `S2`, then you need to create a diamond using virtual inheritance. Doing so will also remove the ambiguity when using `a.h()`, since virtual inheritance will cause only one instance of `A` to appear in `GS`.

```
class s1 : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "s1" << endl; }
};
class s2 : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void h() { cout << "s2" << endl; }
};
```

Comment: With virtual inheritance, `GS` will always look for closest base class with the function it needs? Here `a.h();` will go to `s2::h()` before `A::h()`?

Comment: It is the normal virtual interface rule. The derived class implementation overrides base class interface if the interface is virtual.

Answer (score 4):

Name lookup is based on static type not dynamic type. (And it has to be, since it occurs at compile time not run time.)

Answer (score 3):

Because your pointer is of type `s1` so the compiler knows to call `h()` (inherited from class `A`). Try using a pointer of type `GS` and you'll get an error for the pointer too. In the case of `GS` you are inheriting from `s1` and `s2`, both classes inherit from `A` and thus, multiple(2) definitions of `h()` are found which is ambigious. This is the [dreaded diamond](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html).

Comment: The dreaded diamond you are pointing to isn't exactly OP's problem. Very similar, and virtual inheritance is still the solution, though.

Comment: @AndyG Virtual inheritance may be the "solution". But it isn't clear what is the problem, or even if a problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is because when the compiler evaluates q->h(), q only has one function named 'h' in its scope since it is of type s1.

When the compiler evaluates a.h(), a has two functions named 'h' in its scope. The one from s1 and the one from s2.

The compiler doesn't know which one you wanted to use, so it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

`*q` doesn't give an ambiguity error because its type is `s1*`. This means that the compiler will call `s1::h`, which is unambiguous.