# About virtual function and inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, virtual-inheritance

About the following code:

```
class A {
    A * next;
    static A* tmp;
public:
    A() : next(tmp) {
        if (tmp)
            tmp->next = this;
        tmp = this;

    }
    virtual void print() {
        if (next)
            next->print();
    }
};
class B : public A {
    int a = 1;
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "foo";
        A::print();
    }
};
A* A::tmp;
int main(){
    B c;
    B b;
    b.print();
}
```

Why does `next->print();` leads to `B::print()` and not back to `A::print()`? Since `next` is a static pointer of `A` why does it go to `B`'s function?

EDIT: added `B c;` that I removed accidentally when posting.

Comment: That's strange, on VS15 it does go into next... @NathanOliver

Comment: I removed a line when I posted this, it isn't null now. @NathanOliver

Comment: @NathanOliver it does now: https://ideone.com/qnrfUb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since next is a static pointer of A

`next` is not a *static* pointer. Even though you may have copy-initialized it from a pointer with static storage. But whether it is static has nothing to do with how the member function call works.

> why does it go to B's function?

Because `print` is a virtual function. If a pointer `A* next` points to an instance of `B`, then `next->print()` will call `B::print()`. This is known as virtual or dynamic dispatch.

If you wanted to call `A::print()` instead, then you could have used static dispatch:

```
next->A::print();
```

Of course, if you only ever want to use static dispatch, then it doesn't make any sense to declare the function virtual in the first place.

Comment: It does now.  The OP did post a complete example.  I removed my comment.

Comment: But in my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35095397/4279201 I was told that name look up is based on static type, so in this case, shouldn't a pointer of `A` look for a function of `A` regardless of what type it points to?

Comment: @kuhaku name lookup and virtual dispatch are two separate things. The name `print` is only looked up from the type `A`, but because it happens to be a virtual function, the call will be dispatched virtually.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `next->print();` won't be called at all. If you could debug it, you'll find `next` is null here.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JQUHE78947)

EDIT

With your edited code, the process will be infinate. `next->print();` will lead to `B::print()`, even though the static type of `next` is `A*`, but `A::print()` is a virtual function, and `next` is pointing to an instance of `B` in fact, so dynamic polymorphism works here.

Comment: @kuhaku `B::print()` will be called once indeed. I tried it [here](http://rextester.com/JQUHE78947).